# CSS Designing not show on real time website

Tags: html, css, ftp, filezilla

i have create a web page based on html and css it is working great on localhost but when uploads the files to ftp server then the Css part or design is not show by the ftp server???? so  please help i am stuck!!!

Comment: Can you add more info on the issue you are facing? Like what kinda errors are you getting if any? Or is it simply just a cache issue on your side O.o?

Comment: pls, make sure that the CSS link is not `http://localhost/...`

Comment: Errors in the browser's console? Refresh your cache?

Comment: You are not linking your stylesheet correctly, why not add the HTML that is is you `<head>` section and the relative folder location of your css file? As of now your question is off-topic, you do not have enough information for anyone to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your css is in a separate file from your html, double check that your path to that file is correct.

Here's how it should look if they're both in the same dirctory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: You are making too many assumptions, as of now your answer is just a blind guess.

Comment: I am Asking you about the ftp server not in localhost. you can check the page at http://mohtasim.epizy.com

Comment: but now the problem is solved but i have new problem which is i have create a folder then put all files to the to that folder now problem is that website show first the folder then the site.

Comment: I understand.  Are you certain both the html and the css are making it to the sever?  If so, are they in the same location?  can you post your html?

Comment: For the new issue, you'll need to have an index.html file within that first folder that links to the file in the new folder.  Or, you can change the domain pointer to that new folder, but that wouldn't be any different then putting those files back to the original folder.